# Pygame Key Hold Down

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
while True:

    pencere = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Oyun")

    for olay in pygame.event.get():
        if olay.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 3
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 3
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 3
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 3

    pencere.fill(beyaz)
    pygame.draw.rect(pencere, mavi, (x, y, 40, 60))
    pygame.display.update()
```

When i press navigate buttons, the rectangle goes 3 pixel. But how would I make it so when I hold the keys down?

Comment: Where are x and y initialised? Is there anything else in your main loop? Is `set_mode` definitely called _inside_ your main loop?

Comment: x and y are outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reinitialising the pygame window every time round your loop with `set_mode`. Apparently this resets keyboard input too. (I'm actually surprised this doesn't make the whole window flicker or have other obvious effects.) You should only call `set_mode` *once* and you should do it *before* your main loop.

Comment: I wonder if this is version or OS dependant, the OP's code works for me in PyGame 1.9.6 / Python 3.8.2 / Linux.  No flicker, box moves around OK.

Comment: I reproduced it on Windows. I was honestly pretty surprised - I was not expecting it to repro at all. I imagine it depends very much on OS-specific windowing systems and the details of how pygame and SDL integrate with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import time

key_1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
time.sleep(0.5)
key_2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if key_1 == key_2:
    if key_1[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 3
    if key_1[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 3
    if key_1[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 3
    if key_1[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 3
```

So x and y are updated only if one of the navigation keys is hold down

Comment: Thanks for replying, but still not working and slower than before

Comment: What do you mean by slower? I tested it and it works fine. Maybe you weren't clear enough in your question

Comment: If by slower you the speed that the rectangle is moving, you can decrease the sleep time. But if you choose a too little time window, a single press would be interpreted as a hold down.

Comment: The rectangle moves only once when I hold down the keys, I want it to move as constantly.

Comment: Are you putting my code inside your `while` loop? It should move constantly.

Comment: Yes i put it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

I use a feature like this a lot in my pygame projects.

The basis of it is to set a variable to True if a key is pressed and false if it is released. When you call a function like `move()`, you will check if the movement variables are True or False.

If you pressed the right and left arrows at the same time, there would be no movement.

This is just some of the code I use. Since you are using up and down aswell, you should just add more event checks for up and down and the code should be good to go.

Code:

```
running = True
directions = {"right": False, "left": False}
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                directions['right'] = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                directions['left'] = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                directions['right'] = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                directions['left'] = False
    if directions['right']:
        x += 3
    if directions['left']:
        x -= 3
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but stil when i hold down the navigate buttons, the recangle is not moving as constantly.

Comment: It works fine for me. Please elaborate on what you mean by constantly

Comment: example:

if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
print("hello")

if i hold down up button it prints hello just once. If I want to print it another time, I need to press it again.

Comment: As I said, this code doesn't have the up or down because I didn't use them. It's fairly simple to add them as you can just replicate the functions I had already put down for left and right. Does holding left and right work for you?